# Help with kidney failure in dogs/not eating

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

My chi (10yrs) developed kidney failure, and Dr's said he is a miracle because I've been keeping him alive for 3 yrs. I give sub q IV lactated ringers 3xwk, give Phosphorous reducing med, and make homemade renal diet. Refuses to eat any ready made commercial renal food. Will starve himself before he will eat it. Lately, he is finicky with any food and eating very little. He is very thin. What can I feed him? He doesn't act ill at all and Dr's are amazed with him, and he always rallies.

Comment: My small dog had severe kidney problems caused by bad teeth ; all her teeth were pulled about 4 years ago and she is doing well for a 15 ? year old dog.

Comment: I was also wondering if the teeth was a cause, but they won't attempt to pull them now because of anesthesia. I wish there were a way, but it may be too late.